# What i'm doing wrong? "is not abstract and does not override abstract method retornarId(String)"

Tags: java, android

I thought I was doing everything right here but I must be missing something. Hoping to get explanation about why I'm getting that error and what I should do to fix this type of problem? I'm new to Java/Android.

`

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
        private TextView txtReadedValue;
        private Apptest apptest;
        private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    NfcCallback callback = new NfcCallback() {    
        @Override
        public void retornarValor(String strValor) {    
            txtReadedValue.setText(strValor);
        }
    };
```

`

But I don't know what I should do to solve this error:

**is not abstract and does not override abstract method retornarId(String) in NfcCallback
NfcCallback callback = new NfcCallback() {
^**

Comment: Well I'd suggest overriding the `retornarId(String)` method, which is what the error message says you need to do (as I assume you don't want to create an abstract subclass).

Comment: It is an anonymous class, so it can't be abstract.  But yes, that's what he needs to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ty, fixed